# Bluetooth keyboard and mouse randomly disconnect

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, mouse, bluetooth

Having finally decided to try working standing up during lockdown, I invested in [a bluetooth keyboard](https://www.jellycomb.com/collections/keyboards/products/k62b-3-bluetooth-keyboard) and mouse ([a trackball actually](https://www.logitech.com/en-us/products/mice/mx-ergo-wireless-trackball-mouse.html)). My computer is a pretty decent custom built Windows 10 PC and the bluetooth connection comes from [a dedicated PCI-E card](https://www.gigabyte.com/Motherboard/GC-WB1733D-I-rev-10#ov).

The trouble is that both these devices simultaneously and regularly (but randomly) disconnect themselves (from a few minutes to a few hours apart). They reconnect as soon as I open the Windows 10 Bluetooth settings page (I kept my USB keyboard and mouse plugged in). I occasionnally used Bluetooth headphones before and I never noticed this behavior. The only difference I can spot is that both the keyboard and the mouse seem to be Low Energy devices, but I don't know what to make of that.

This is pretty disturbing, especially during focused work... Any pointers?

Comment: NB: I have tried and purposefully listened to my bluetooth headphones while using said keyboard and mouse for the last ~90' and no disconnection occurred...

Answer (score 1):

Check Power Saving setting

[enter link description here](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/how-to-adjust-power-and-sleep-settings-26f623b5-4fcc-4194-863d-b824e5ea7679)

Comment: Sleep and hibernation are disabled for this computer, and disconnection occurs when I am using the computer. Furthermore there is no Power Mangement tab on these devices in the Device Manager.